# ReactJS - Going back in nested routes with Reacter Router Dom V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

My initial page is

```
http://localhost:3000/home
```

With a navigation bar I go to a list of products in:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/all/
```

When I click a product in the list I go to:

```
 http://localhost:3000/products/banana/
```

Now if I click Back on the browser or if I make a button with the new useNavigate and try to do `navigate(-1)` I go to `/home` in both examples.

How can I make it so I go to `/products/all/` with useNavigate and hopefully I can do change the browser interaction too?

Comment: Are you using `<Link />` everywhere? Because if you're using <a> instead, it'll basically work but the app will reload and the navigation history is gone.

Comment: @decayed.cell , how did you navigate to the products/all and products/banana ? like show us the code on that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I was using `replace:true` when I was navigating with useNavigate from the list of the products to a particular product.
Sorry if it seeemed that I didn't give enough information but this solved my issue.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate